# Tools for testing transfer speed to an already mounted SMB?

Tags: networking, samba, latency

Say I have mounted `/mnt/mount_test` as a samba mount and I want to test the transfer speed from my local system to that mount.

I want to know: after the mount is mounted, what transfer speeds am I getting?

I have this FIO script but I'm not sure if that properly represents transfer from my system to the SMB system?

```
fio --loops=5 --size=1G --directory=$TEST_DIR --stonewall --ioengine=libaio --verify=0 --direct=1 \
  --name=Seqread --bs=1m --rw=read --iodepth=64 \
  --name=Seqwrite --bs=1m --rw=write --iodepth=64 \
  --name=512Kread --bs=512k --rw=randread --iodepth=64 \
  --name=512Kwrite --bs=512k --rw=randwrite --iodepth=64 \
  --name=4kQD32read --bs=4k --rw=randread --iodepth=32 \
  --name=4kQD32write --bs=4k --rw=randwrite --iodepth=32
```

What I could also do is copy a file with `dd` like so:

```
time sudo dd status=progress if=/home/testuser/10GB_FILE.txt of=/mnt/mount_test/10GB_FILE.txt bs=128M
```

Would this properly test the speed or am I missing something?